# How to enable internet on Virtual machines over a internal network through gateway?

Tags: networking, network-programming, virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-neutron

I have few virtual machines on a private software defined network. All these virtual machines does not internet access yet. What i am trying is setting up a new virtual machine which will have internet access, and this vm will act as a gateway for my other Virtual Machine.

For Example:

[image]

So when i hit https://google.com from vm1, vm2 or vm3 , the request should go to internet gateway (which is the other vm as as shown in diagram).

Is there any way to achieve this kind of architecture? Please Help!

Comment: Not sure whether this would help you or not. But definitely look into iptables with forwarding. You are on the right track and basically, the "vm which has internet acess" is your router actually. you need to know which interface has the connection to the public network and forward the traffic from the vm1/2/3 to that interface.

Comment: LucasH.Xu so  i have added a iptables rule which states that when source is "192.168.7.0/24" and destination is "0.0.0.0" then transfer the packet to public address of vm which has internet. I hope it works : ) Could not test due to some reasons.